# Pristine Bit Checking

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, restricted-source, pristine-programming

Write a program/function that takes two integers in the range \$0\$ to \$255\$ inclusive, and returns whether the binary forms of the numbers are exactly one bit different.

For example, \$1\$ and \$0\$ have binary forms `00000001` and `00000000`, which are one bit apart. Similarly, \$152\$ and \$24\$ are `010011000` and `000011000`, so they return true.

***However***, your code must be **pristine**, such that if any one bit in your program is flipped, it should throw an error. For example, if your program was the single byte `a` (`01100001`), then all the 8 possible modified programs:

```
á ! A q i e c `
```

must throw an error. Make sure you are modifying by *bytes* (e.g. the `á` up there is actually representing the byte \$225\$, not the actual two byte character `á`).

#### Test cases:

```
0,1     => Truthy
1,0     => Truthy
152,24  => Truthy
10,10   => Falsey
10,11   => Truthy
11,12   => Falsey
255,0   => Falsey
```

### Rules:

- Provide a testing framework that can verify that your program is properly pristine, since there will be a lot of possible programs (number of bytes*8), or else a complete proof of pristineness.

  - *Please* make sure your program is valid before you post it.
- Output needs to be either truthy/falsey (either way around is fine), or else two distinct non-error values
- Errors can be runtime, compiler, interpreter etc.

Comment: If anyone's looking for a way to generate all possible variations of their solution, this Japt programme *should* (someone please double check) do the job: https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=rK5jIKT5VDggrKNay15FpVnDrM1kw8PLo2hFWMPDY2lVILc&input=ImEi

Comment: Here's one in Python as well: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDBbsMgEETvfAVyDuzGbWTnFCHxF71ZKLIxaTZKAREOSat@uwttSSr1tJo3u6OBcEtH77aL8bNVTdMs42SWPIdePveasRDJJV5ctuIv9pL4wUee6SWRs6wY@4mcEmJz8uRAfMhuN32KTV57GxP4OINBLEeGk/tOQlbkRKmAOLpXC2froGYhSsar2B/OFIKdubqjQeZT3YquF8OdFaSU6IRu/7K2l/o37BFUu5pjhPw6qPqKT9ufqtfS7J0CrAdKNsK/NqjXO0TGH99TreUL "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: I'm trying to think of a way to make Pristine machine code.  If a bit is flipped in a register field, it just reads the wrong register without crashing.  Perhaps the code could checksum itself.  Without that requirement x86 can do this in two instructions (xor and popcnt)

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 35 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:(a^b)&-(a^b)in[a^b or[]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHdbsIgGL3nKYgmAyya0szEkHSXewLvms7QFidLpYSypW7Zs3dgrc65jRv4zl8OYA5u1@ikL5tKppPJpK/FvqgEFLTgWDwV5G5@3JTO/AYbm@V573UZ43OWAyA7WWK0TVEUEggAxirt4BbHlBE4hWGlD3BtX93ucCYZjf8hlwlN7o/8L6TPPXk9@SjqVl6T7Ez@dDLKkr@cyXJJb2IHFoApXMvWqxoLPdI6pSUIt90USqcILV4apTH64PGq@EQLL9sLhxtb4ZKQYCqh0nB4njAWygXACv0scS01HrMI4QCOw2ZbK2NkBdMzlHFvzSMUM5SdsQClKYpRHn3HIsbzU9glaOxa7iz2N8Pj3BGaDFW70OxdGTzLlJMW37Qh@WxFCIDOHnxZeP39o8rzl3/05@GV0ZuoVcURtdKcki962ZXSOG5E2/Zf)

Uses the power-of-two check `n&-n==n`, eliminating the `n==0` false positive.

For reference, these are the pairs of one-char binary operators that are one bit apart, making them hard to use:

```python
+ /
- /
* +
% -
< |
< >
```

Fortunately, `&` and `^` are not among these.

Also note that `==` can become `<=`, and `+` can become the comment character `#`.

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:bin(a^b).count(`+True`)is+True
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFBbsIwELz7FRYcbBMXxVGRUKT02Bdwi1JwElNcBcdyTBVa9e2pTUiA0tYn78zsaHZXH@2uVlFX1KVIJpNJV/F9XnLIaR7nUmH@kpN5UR@UxZtgZQ5iQ2Rz@nROnbL4gWUAiFYUGG0TFHgfAoA2Ulm4xSFlBE6hf8kTdG12dxxJRsN/yEVEo8cT/wvpfM@9jnzmVSNuSTaSPzsZZdFfndFiQe9sexaAKVyJxqlqAx3SWKkE8NOu3ZoShOZvtVsX@ozDZf6F5k625xbXpsQFIb6pgFLBfj2@zKX1gOHqVeBKKDx4ERIDOBTrbSW1FiVMRih1d7FZgEKG0hHzUJKgEGXBNRawODubXYyGrMXOYDcZHuqW0KiP2vpkH1LjWSqtMPguDclmS0IAtObowsLb8w8qx1/u6P79ltE7r2QZI2qEPjtf9KIthLax5k3TfQM)

Taking [TFeld's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182836/20260) `lambda a,b:bin(a^b).count('1')==1` and making it pristine by changing the 1's to `+True` and `==` to `is`. Thanks to Jo King for 1 byte.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>72</s> <s>67</s> 50 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:sum(map(int,'{:b}'.format(a^b)))is+True
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHRToMwFH3vVzTbQ9tRF0pcspDgo1@wN4JLgeJqoDSlM0zjt2Mrgzmn8sQ9556T03P1yR5aFQ1FW4pksVgMNW/ykkNO87g7NrjhGktlKXqP8w@0rlrTcIv5U04IkV2wM0cxOFnK4juWASB6UWBUJSjwhgQAbZwaVjikjMAl9F/yAJ3MHk4zyWj4D7mJaHT/xf9COt@z1pGPvO7ENclm8qeSURb9pYw2G3pjO7IALOFOdG6rNdAhnZVKAP/afS5VgtD6pZUKu77C7bfGWlPighAvKqBUcKzHj7m0HjBcPQtcC4UnL0JiAKdhX9VSa1HCZIbS2EmzAIUMpTPmoSRBIcqC71jA4uxsdjGashYH42@Mp7knNBqj9j7Zm9R4lUorDL5JQ7LVlhAArTm5sPD6/NOW4y93dP9jy@iV17KMETVCn50v@6IvhLax5l03fAI)

<sub>-5 bytes, thanks to Jo King</sub>

---

Returns `True`/`False` for for truthy/falsey.

The program is basically the same as `lambda a,b:bin(a^b).count('1')==1`, but without numbers and other chars which work when bit-flipped.

Works by making sure that almost everything is a named function (which are all quite pristine)

The pristine test at the end flips a single bit (for every bit), and tries the function on an input. If that works (correct or not), that variation is printed. No printed programs = pristine function.

Answer (score 8):

## Java 8, <s>68</s> <s>61</s> <s>56</s> 45 bytes

```java
a->b->(a.bitCount(a^b)+"").equals(-~(a^a)+"")
```

-11 bytes thanks to *@EmbodimentOfIgnorance*, replacing [constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#org.w3c) `java.awt.Font.BOLD` with `-~(a^a)`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lY8xa8MwEIV3/4ojk0RrEZt6SuKhgUCGThlLC2dHNnIVybFOgVDSv@6qxU2hS5Xt8d538F2HJ0y7/dtYa3QOnlCZ9wTAEZKqoQur8KS0aLypSVkjNlNYbg3JVg73cdCjtVqiKUtoYDViWlZpyVBUitbWG2L4WvG72YwLefSoHUs/QoXf1bhIglHvKx2MJrGTVXs4BFm2o0GZ9vkFcGgd/3IH2J0dyYOwnkQfVtKGNQL7Xp/ZnE8h43zxH5zx61UEXOQ/eP4Qw/@qzG/Do9Sv7lkegedF8efXS3IZPwE)

**Explanation:**

The shortest base function would be:

```java
a->b->a.bitCount(a^b)==1
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lY9Bi4MwEIXv/oo5GliDynpq9dCFhR568rhsYbQqsWkiZlKQpb/dTcG20EvT24P3De@bHs8Y9YfjXEs0BnYo1F8AYAhJ1NC7llsSkrdW1SS04t9LWG8VNV0zfvhBG61lg6oooIV8xqioogJ5JehLW0Uh7iuW58m8Ctz4YCvpxheHsxYHODmvsKRRqO7nF3DsDLtqApSToebEtSU@uJakCluOwyCnMGZLSBhbvYITdr/ygLP0hqefPvxDJX4P91K/uyepB55m2dOvl@Ay/wM)

This is modified so there isn't a digit, `=`, nor one of the `+/*` operands in it for numeric calculations (so the `+` for String-concatenation is fine):

The `+""` and `.equals` are to compare by `String.equals(String)` instead of `int==int`.
NOTE: `Integer.equals(int)` could be used here, but would be more bytes, since both the `.bitCount` and `java.awt.Font.BOLD` are primitive `int` instead of `Integer`-objects, so an additional `new Integer(...)` would be required to transform one of the two to an `Integer`-object, before we could use the `.equals`.

Comment: (int)Math.log(Math.E) is 21 bytes

Comment: [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY0xT8MwEIXn@Fd4tFFzgjmQAVQkBsTQEYF0Tk241Dmb@FypqvrbQ4TC1O1775PeG/CI9bA/zDSmOIkelgxFKMBNo666r8KdUGR4XqFRXcCcdT7rLCjU6X9z/8Liez9trgr9GGPwyG2r8WHGunV1@@YG30kG/1MwZGOIxb6ifEOIvfmDrd0gOJKnWFgMfjpr50ZVqbiwvK7nx0h7PSKx2clE3L9/aJz6bM@qqnanLH6EWATS4iSwQcCUwsnc2hXurF02L@oy/wI "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ExpiredData Thanks, actually just found a shorter constant with `java.awt.Font.BOLD`, but your `Objects.equals` is a nice golf, thanks!

Comment: @ExpiredData Actually, `Objects` is part of the `java.util.` import, so I have to add that to the byte-count I'm afraid, making it 69 bytes.. :(

Comment: Would `-~(a^a)` work for 1?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Thanks, that indeed seems to work.

Answer (score 7):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 56 bytes

```c
d(a,b){return(sizeof((char)d))^__builtin_popcount(a^b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBDoIwDIbvPEWPnWIiJnqZPIkRMsbQJTrI3Iwb4dlxSFCM9tC06ff/TctXJ877vkQWF6TVwlit8Ca9qCtEfmaalIRkeV5YeTFS5U3d8NoqgywrCO16qQxcmVQ4FEyfeAyDChahvh@OBNoIQgxTF3v6aqpaA3pIYU3Bwx422x2F5dJP8JtxI@M@jJszk7EWN3sxgS3Rx47QH8Aq8WgEN6IMEP45xmfBOE0hCeJvdQU42aczH/JFDTG@DpLP9i4aczQbr2nU9U8)

Returns `0` if the pair differ by 1, non-zero otherwise. Slightly unusual for C, unless you consider it returning `EXIT_SUCCESS` if the pair differ by 1, any other value otherwise.

Uses `sizeof((char)d))` to produce the constant `1` in a pristine way while also forcing the function name to be pristine.

It then XORs that 1 with the popcount of the XOR of the arguments. Luckily the `^` symbol is easy to keep pristine, as is the very long identifier `__builtin_popcount`.

Meanwhile, here is the script used to test the solution:

```c
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_FILE=$1
FOOT_FILE=$2
TMP_SRC=temp.c

LENGTH="$(wc -c <"$SOURCE_FILE")"
BITS=$((LENGTH*8))

cat "$SOURCE_FILE" >"$TMP_SRC"
cat "$FOOT_FILE" >>"$TMP_SRC"
if gcc -w $TMP_SRC -o t.out >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    if ./t.out; then
        echo "Candidate solution..."
    else
        echo "Doesn't even work normally..."
        exit
    fi
else
    echo "Doesn't even compile..."
    exit
fi

for i in $(seq 1 $BITS); do
    ./flipbit "$i" <"$SOURCE_FILE" >"$TMP_SRC"
    cat "$FOOT_FILE" >>"$TMP_SRC"
    if gcc -w $TMP_SRC -o t.out >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "Testing flipped bit $i:"
        cat "$TMP_SRC"

        ./t.out >/dev/null 2>&1
        STATUS=$?
        if [ "$STATUS" -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "It works!"
            exit
        elif [ "$STATUS" -eq 1 ]; then
            echo "It doesn't work..."
            exit
        else
            echo "It crashes"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Which uses the `./flipbit` tool I wrote whose source is simply:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int bittoflip = atoi(argv[1]) - 1;
    int ch;

    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        if (bittoflip < 8 && bittoflip >= 0) {
            putchar(ch ^ (1 << bittoflip));
        } else {
            putchar(ch);
        }

        bittoflip -= 8;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The tricky bits were:

- Whitespace: All whitespace (including newlines) have pristine twins that will work similarly
- Comparison: `=` doesn't work well, since it can be a comparison in every case it could appear. Similarly `-` doesn't work well. Thus `^` is used to assert equality with 1.
- Variable names: f would clash with b, so had to use d as the function name instead.

Comment: How do you keep the `^` operator pristine? If the bits on that were changed, what's to stop it from becoming a different operator? This would still compile, but would just give you the wrong answer. Am I misunderstanding something about the meaning of the word "pristine" here?

Comment: By flipping *only one* bit, `^` can only be changed into any one of `_\ZVN~Þ` or the unprintable character at codepoint 30. `~` is the only one of those which is an operator, but it's only a unary operator.

Comment: Other answers have found `-~(a^a)` works as a `1`.  IDK if that helps, because then you'd need another way to make the function pristine.  Maybe call `d(a,b)` *after* the `return`, so it doesn't execute but has to parse.

Comment: I don't suppose we can use [Test if a bitboard have only one bit set to 1](//stackoverflow.com/q/12483843) `a&&!(a&(a-1))` bithack to test for having exactly 1 bit set while being pristine.  And it might even be longer than `__builtin_popcount`.  Plus you need the number multiple times, so you'd need `a^=b;` and then use `a`.

Comment: @Peter Cordes I looked into such solutions as well. Unfortunately `!` is one bit off from ` ` so it is very tricky to incorporate. Similarly `-` and `=` can always be swapped as can `+` and `*` or `/` (and usually `;`) so those operators are pretty much not going to work.

Comment: Can you do `(sizeof(char))` instead of `(sizeof((char)d))` to save 3 bytes? https://tio.run/##bZDBDoIwDIbvPEWPnWIiJnqZPIkRMsbQJTrI3Iwb4dlxSFCM9tC06ff/TctXJ877vkQWF6TVwlit8Ca9qCvkZ6YJyfK8sPJipMqbuuG1VQZZVhDa9VIZuDKpcCiYPvEYBg0sQn0/HAm0EYQYpi729NVUtQb0kMKagoc9bLY7Csuln@A340bGfRg3ZyZjLW72YgJboo8doT@AVeLRCG5EGSD8c4zPgnGaQhLE3@oKcLJPZz7kixpi/Bskn@1dNOZoNl7TqOuf

Comment: Or even use `__LINE__` instead of `sizeof(char)`.  I think its fine to assume that your function will be on line 1 of your .c file.  Or even `unix` is defined to 1 on TIO, and probably most other Linux.

Comment: The main reason for the char-casted sizeof is to get `d` baked into the source in the fewest bytes possible. Otherwise `d` (or whatever you name the function) can just be changed and the code will still work. Even `(__LINE__)` with `d();` wont work because `d();` can be changed to any other letter and it will still compile since the function never has to be called, thus isn't linked.

Comment: @LambdaBeta If the name of the function changes, then there will be a link error, even if d is not self-referential.  I think this is sufficient, personally.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Nick Kennedy.

```r
dpois(log2(bitwXor(scan(),scan())),T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtBCsMgFET3/xQu/dSKSqWbHiOLQsiiTbEIQUu01BBydqsGCl29YebNnA25HIl5uzFa7yjnHFdItROwVEw2xFZDGG/uT8a1iKVI5EAkLH2fhmHLj5e3gU7@qejdxs/Vz7Q@KbIdiKzDvIGhghGJhZIR0agVU6eW6iR@abeKJlVNSuv6yIUg1Rm@) (Thanks to Giuseppe for setting up the TIO properly.)

[Proof that it is pristine](https://tio.run/##XZDRSsQwEEXf@xVDQZhAd9HCsiDrkx8gSB98ECVts9usMamZqe2y@O110kUUoZBm7p0zNxPneYLdCvK2D5bQhUOJteXxKUSkRntUxeVQqqhUnqVL8u8H37ANItyU26wPRKlKuu/dCcl8vDrj0TedjjhJ66/fqh/X9e32T/2o4JwBRLOAOJ7wTENNLP0FWPlUqkc9VuF@oUrAhK/Cox7xn1UGalqLGUt4gaOEF7T51A57Hckgm4nhDiRZ9pUk6zsTLRPK@AJymb4yMYaYJ11ljWakPlrPe8wfBoawh6sW0qttbZ1lK6mbzjRvpi2SIpjBsWBBtrWQ1s8@L0CWcuAOU6NEpOH98qvUXG42IJucvwE) (using [Nick Kennedy's checker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182883/86301)).

Outputs 0 for falsey, and a positive value for truthy, which I understand [is acceptable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/86301) since R will interpret these as False and True.

Explanation: `bitwXor(a,b)` gives (as an integer) the bitwise XOR between `a` and `b`. To check whether it is a power of 2, check whether its log in base 2 is an integer. The function `dpois` gives the probability density function of the Poisson distribution: its value is 0 for non-integer values, and something positive for non-negative integers. The `T` is there because `dpois` requires a second argument (any positive real works, and `T` is interpreted as 1).

If we insist on outputting to distinct values, the following version outputs FALSE or TRUE in 42 bytes (thanks to Giuseppe for -8 bytes):

```r
dpois(log2(bitwXor(scan(),scan())),T)%in%F
```

and [is also pristine](https://tio.run/##XVDfS8MwEH7vX3EUBhfohhbGQOaT4KsgffBBlKxL15s1qbmr6xj@7fWyIYoQSPh@3ZeL0zTCeg75tg/E2IVdiRuSw1OIyLX1aIrLZUxRmRn52X2eJSSZmsHXQkHZ63KV9YE5oWz7vjsiu4/Xznn0dWsjjur/1ZP5UV3drP7gewOnDCC6c5DEI5542LCovwDSYxIe7aEKd@dUbZniq/BoD/hPqgMtL1SMJbzAXn@g0e7TdtjbyA7FjQK3oM2yr0SRb10kYdTxBeQ6fe5iDDFPvMlqK8h9JC8N5g@DQGhgtoX0a9pQR0Laum5d/ea2RWI0ZuhEY0G3dU5aPPu8AF3KTlpMRq3Iw/vlacxULpegm5y@AQ). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtBCsIwFET3/xTZFPIxhiQY3Lj2BC6E0oVWIoGSSBsxpfTsMUlBcPWGmTdjMuS0J@bt@mC9o5xzXCCWTsBcMNgp1Bqm/ub@ZFyymItIdkTC3Lax69b0eHk70cE/Fb3b8Ln6kZYnRbYBkV2wsa45pxUMFYxIzJSMiEqtmDrUVCbxS5uVNalKUlqXR8oEqY7wBQ)

Comment: Well done on getting something so much smaller than mine! You could replace `pi` with `T` to save a byte (still pristine). Also your TIO doesn’t correspond to your answer at the moment.

Comment: @NickKennedy Thanks! (And thanks for writing the code to check it is pristine!).
The TIO I linked to is a modified version that checks all the test cases. I'll add a TIO to the actual code, but I can't figure out how to get TIO to run properly with two calls to `scan()`; do you have an idea? (The code works fine on a computer.)

Comment: @NickKennedy Maybe something [like this?](https://tio.run/##VYtBCsMgFET3/xQu/dSKSqWbHiOLQsiiTbEIQUu01BBydqsGCl29YebNnA25HIl5uzFa7yjnHFdItROwVEw2xFZDGG/uT8a1iKVI5EAkLH2fhmHLj5e3gU7@qejdxs/Vz7Q@KbIdiKzDvIGhghGJhZIR0agVU6eW6iR@abeKJlVNSuv6yIUg1Rm@) for getting the TIO and the code to match?

Comment: @Giuseppe Wonderful, thanks!

Comment: your second version could use `F` instead of `exp(-Inf)`, along the same lines as Nick's `T` :-)

Comment: @Giuseppe Duh! I spent a long time looking for pristine code to get integers (`floor(sqrt(pi))` or `exp(exp(-Inf))` for 1 for example) and never thought of the simple `F` and `T`!

Comment: Finally, my deleted mathematica answer in use `IntegerQ@*Log2@*BitXor`. This is the only time I wish mathematica threw more errors!

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 83 bytes

```r
t(identical(sum(.<-as.double(intToBits(Reduce(bitwXor,scan())))),sum(T^el(.[-T]))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v0QjMyU1ryQzOTFHo7g0V0PPRjexWC8lvzQpJ1UjM68kJN8ps6RYIyg1pTQ5VSMps6Q8Ir9Ipzg5MU9DEwR0QJpC4lJzNPSidUNiQUL/DY3MFYxMTf8DAA)

[Proof that this is pristine](https://tio.run/##XZBhS8MwEIa/91ccBeECbdHBGMj8oj9AGP0gqJM0vdnMmtTk6jaGv71eCqIY8iHc@96TuzdM0xHWJeSMtiXH1uge4/iO1brUsWr92PSE1nHtby1H3FA7GsLG8uHBhyIa7VClU6Smeks9Vo9l/ZxKeZbkRN@NzrD1YjW4WC6Lq8VKZYOPMYlRD0N/wkgfLz05dKbTAY9C/G2z6sd1eb36U98rOGcAgWYQhxOe49hElv4CrFyV6kEfan83U33AhK/9Rh/wn1U@lI3FjAvYwl4WEDR9Sh6DDpGQ6chwAzJZ9pUk6zoKKRP5vpAAw6mkEHzIk64yoxnjECS6Heb3I4PfwUULaWvb2N6ylalNR@aN2iIpghl7FixIaDOpenJ5ARLKK3eYGmXEFPP8VGqSKEGinL4B)

Working around the fact that `as.integer`, `as.double` etc. are only a bit away from `is.integer`, `is.double` etc. was the hardest bit. In the end, using `sum(T^el(.[-T])` as a way of both generating a one and checking that `as.double` has returned a >1 length vector was the best I could do. The wrapping `t` is to handle the fact that otherwise `identical` can become `ide~tical`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), 20 bytes

```julia
(a,b)->ispow2(a⊻b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/59m@18jUSdJU9cus7ggv9xII/FR1@4kzf8FRZl5JTl5GmkaBjqGCiCgqamsEFJUWpJRyYWQNNQxwCNpaqRjZIJLEmiuAVSnW2JOcSq6pCFOYw11DI1w6TQyNdVBNfY/AA)

Here is a [pristine validator](https://tio.run/##bdY9ThtBAIbhFlapOACyR0HMmFmwbIk/YRB0qUCiSJNix8ssHnu9rGfX2BYSSKkiInEAuAGUqRIK7mIkCi7hGOq3/J7vAm93mDqzNZslslCt0k@CSsVemlTmxhdWCilqRU0oWdd1JZSav6Uf2iA2ZdyZj8SkhQ1sdhaMW96MhBBBx@i2CvddkV@MGtJMb5/bKlgg3CasEGrCGqEilFXCQ8IBoSO0hDFhRGhSwi@Ee4RfCSXhOmFIqAXhEaEn7BImhBFhTNh2hIuEO4RVwpBwjVASqj5hQNgiXCFUhBuEmjC8JlwmXCfcJNwl3CM8INxXhN8IJ4SGsE/YI@wQuibhKWFMeEU4IhwQesKiTnhCGBGOCUtCTzggzDcIjwlvCM8Je4R9wozwYovwO@E54Q1hQTgkvCQcecIlQkG4S7hJWCdsEjY6hAuE24QVQk1YI1SEskp4SDggdISWMCaMCM074RvhK@H0kfCe8CfhHeEvwt@Etw@ET4R/CF8I/xL@I3wWhEeEnrBLmBBGhDFh2xEuEu4QVglDwjVCGXwUcO5dVkqTTWSiizx1pRzr1R/Zqu5Zm9t@Xk5an92slJrN/gM) that tries running each modified anonymous function against some input, and neither passes successfully. Note that the code has a multi-byte unicode character, and some possible outputs from bit flipping are not even included, as those produce invalid UTF-8 strings.

Comment: `x` and `y` are one bit apart, so [I believe this is a counter example.](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/59m@1@jQqdSU9cus7ggv9xIo/JR1@5Kzf8FRZl5JTl5GmkaBjqGCiCgqamsEFJUWpJRyYWQNNQxwCNpaqRjZIJLEmiuAVSnW2JOcSq6pCFOYw11DI1w6TQyNdVBNfY/AA "Julia 0.7 – Try It Online") `y` and `x` are also 1 bit off `9` and `6` respectively.

Comment: Damn, while thinking about complex things, I absolutely missed the simplest one. Hopefully, changing the variables will fix it.

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 37 bytes

```cs
a=>b=>a!=b&((a^b)&-(a^b)).Equals(a^b)
```

The `a=>b=>` part cannot be changed, or else the function is invalid.

In `a!=b`, the `=` cannot be changed since `int` cannot be converted to `bool`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc89C4MwEAbgvb/CLpKDWHKHmdpkq1PHQrdCIkoDotSPob8@jQqFaLMk93DvHSmHrBycL6a2vLh25L@H7bpG61p5o7RV2hyVTRkzTwtptlxwur4n0wxL4c@HR@/G6ubaitVMAEOA2BACb00SMMp3POfFX92PDXORtkpSruu84JjMR@nk3k/j63NALrYiiVMeSYiJtacIf6xWwTiFHCnqCVt5lPoC)

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>128</s> <s>101</s> <s>77</s> <s>70</s> <s>61</s> 74  bytes

*-27 bytes thanks to [Ascii-Only](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39244/ascii-only)*

```cs
a=>b=>{var d=Math.Log(a^b,(int)Math.E);return d.Equals((int)Math.Abs(d));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc49C8IwEAbg3V/R8Q6qtMFONQGHOtXZTchHq4GaYpIKIv72GOsgto733Mt7J91SOh12g5EbdTf8omU6Dtr4VPR9x1jS0sApE5Q9btwmiu65P6/q/gT8KFKIQRylwtI2frAmUavqOvDOwXe5FQ4UYvkM5eJgtW9qbRpoIUfIIv9YhpEnlhcEgaxn/M5mf3VeEW/lZKqkKD4vhBc)

You have to be quite creative to get numbers in C# without using literals. Only uses ^ operator. Variables a,b are all more than 1 bit away from each other and everything else is a keyword/name.

Comment: you don't need to count bits - checking if it's a power of 2 between 1 and 128 inclusive is enough

Comment: @ASCII-only Good luck checking that in a reasonable number of bytes when we can't use integers nor `+/*=` for mathematical or validating operations. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen C# has enums too :(. [damnit](https://tio.run/##bY7BasJAEIbvPkXxNINxSYI5afbQklxsQTDQW2Gzjnbpuqu7m4JPHzcWShu9/fPNxz8j/Vx61dedkStlQvIbWms150/7shclb0v@Ys03ucAauw1OmQOIjzaBaOKbCJ@s1tY6uMUKkW1JkwywK3k02EY4T7CbTafDqjsCsurcCe0htnqraU0X1oh2/md8FvLLn4Qk7JeTd6cCvSpDsIcMIUX8z1KMeMSyIkfIF3d4cNOH9L4i3sryMc2L4ueF/go)

Comment: [101?](https://tio.run/##bc7PC4IwFAfwe39FdHqPbKjkqdwhq1NUoNAt2HTGwrbaZtBfb0YQqN0en/d9P3I7y61strXKl1I571dwrStKx2XcsJjymCZaPYVxJNOpM1JdgJ25B20Ss9ddJLoQZL3a11WFJK1vUMS07ZEjM1ZAMZ1MEMnmUbPKQnfowK8id9gsRicjndhJJaCEAMFH7JqPLfcsiEKEcD7gT9b/q8MV7a0g7GsYRd8Xmjc)

Comment: @ASCII-only Ik. And with some flags in the Visual C# Interactive Compiler you don't even need the imports. Still, how would you check if it's a power of 2 and within that range? Usually when I check if it's a power of 2 I use `a&~-a==0`, but the `==0` should then already be replaced, and the `&`, `-`, `~` possibly as well (haven't checked those yet).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen `.Equals` works in C# :P. and i was thinking an `Enumerable.Range` and a `Some` (?) but maybe that doesn't work?

Comment: @ASCII-only Ah of course, `.Equals` works with primitives in C#. Well, in that case go right ahead. ;p haha. Hmm, `Enumerable.Range` might perhaps be possible. I'm not too skilled with C#, so I'll leave that to you guys. :)

Comment: @ASCII-only I get [121 bytes](https://tio.run/##bc5NC8IwDIDhu7/CYwJa1uK8aHvwCwQVUcGb0G1RC7UV1yH@@jkRhG3ewsNLkjTvp7kpF4VLx8aF3m9IvLdKdc@y1FIlUs1dcaOHTiyxnXYXAqgqPLzuNPUZsfntHl69ui1d4ENke7KUBsikWutwZVv/hKxRziabwlpENvUuaONy0KcEy1Hn@DCBVsYRnIEjRIh1i7DihvFYIIhBiz9t9FfbK6pbXDRVxPH3hfIN "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online") with enumerable.range (Int64 better than Uint16)

Comment: [sadly, it really is longer :(](https://tio.run/##bc5NC4JAEAbge7@i4wzYopJdyoU@DIKKiKJbsOpawrprukv4680QCq3b8DDvOxOVo6hM67WR0SyV2voMoVKC0mHi18ynoU8DaTJesFBwcmTyxgGaLTxVOV@qmJMgy3Vlde28kdqZIJnLCmKfAruGSIKHYaJs0zum7@SgngCxMk3zN7pa7I0QVoyI9XRwKVLNt6nkkICDYCN2zcaGe@Z4LoI7/uH3rv1XfyuaW47bV9fz2hfqFw) (`Uint16`, not `Int16`)

Comment: O_o another -24. btw you no longer use `+`

Comment: Invalid, the `=` can be replaced with a `-`,see https://tio.run/##bc4xD4IwEAXg3V/heJcUQhuZkCYOOOHsZnKtoE2wjbYM/vpacTCC4/vycve0z7Q3cT9avT0/Ld2MZlMwNjDl3CDluq8j1VLVEig7ULjmrbsAnRSDVMJJGsS8uY80ePjiTnkgxCpWq@PDhK41toMeOEKR9McKTDwzXgoEsVnwu1v81eWJ9IuLuYqy/EyILw

Comment: Fixed @EmbodimentofIgnorance, seems odd I thought that would work but ran it and tio threw an exception. Must have had something else broken at the time

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6 in strict mode), 61 bytes

```javascript
(y,z,e)=>eval(`(y${(e='^=z)*!(y&~-y)')!='^=z)*!(y&~-y)'||e}`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7RCoIwGEbvfYpfiLaFppN2FXbZE3Qdiv2WMVy4KcysVzcvgkJqtx@H851r3uW6aKqbCWt1wpG0GkGbpioM2XoSDZTpSG3QB8jSHXa5pBm1izvFlBzTnq18apfP0DLC/PkyDPjI2FioWiuJa6nOtKQAcQDAGYMogkPTmov15gSfiNhBcJEEkGxcDj698Ldjn0uNvwlnB586eOJwJEJ8Sv@8TKUgvonxBQ) or [Make sure that all modified programs are wrong](https://tio.run/##dZHdbuIwEIXveYohqtZ2Sa2CdqWqga4Quxd7V4lLREXqDpCK2NQxYQNNX52O89OllVaRovGcyTfHJ89xHmfKJlt3pc0TnvIURmDxZZdY5CxPmYhOigTqBrwIDyGK0R3m8YYveHFx5DhiD6ODuOzy4tvbVSGY6H7tvL5iuRBB1OksjeVbZ4l1HYEvhuDZcoN65dZVq9cTcOwA@NHHxNWjvhjCTVW0AwAa95Pa2UxK6UHz6FyYEW5O6tTZRK/k0pp0so6tl/j5iFRNd@y4gAfow3DoN4mallWGmw/ks0k0Z6zRtnGWkTioT84WjTXyv9OKlCqpgO0y9JxEORYF0PN1Q/hg9Ntznkq703/0xGiHfx1f/B91caSqDERUreP9H4MQBt/FIvQQZTF22FKOpWg2ltVbxU6tOVKWAM1iZXRmNvQ3zIoTNwReW6P7wU9gs21sMwoS0Fpj5wxuqUdOXZJi2xN0N0ZPD1A6UwfPxderXp8bSZbVGvGR3LmN4H48nf7@FYSfEnNra/bQav9gZac8nd4B)

Comment: Oh my gosh I didnt realize I clicked a code golf link and saw this answer out of context and almost had a heart attack. Like, OMG NO

Comment: @Marie Caution! You can only stare at this code with certified golf glasses. Otherwise, it may burn your retina. :p

Answer (score 2):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), <s>47</s> 36 bytes

```
a,b->a.bitCount(a^b).equals(-~(a^a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/J9mW/0/USdJ1y5RLymzxDm/NK9EIzEuSVMvtbA0MadYQ7cOyE3U1Pxfy8VVUJSZV5KTp5CmYaBjqInENdQxQOGaGukYmaCIADUYoAugGmGoY2iELGBkago09T8A)

Adapted version of [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)'s Java answer.

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 37 bytes

```matlab
@(c,e)eq(nnz(de2bi(bitxor(c,e))),eye)
```

Sorry, no TIO link, because I can't get the test suite to work under Octave. Thanks @ExpiredData for some helpful comments.

Test suite:

```matlab
program = '@(c,e)eq(nnz(de2bi(bitxor(c,e))),eye)';
number_of_characters = nnz(program);
success = [];
for character_counter = 0 : number_of_characters
    for bit_no = 1:8
        prog_temp = program;
        if(character_counter > 0)
            prog_temp(character_counter) = bitxor(double(prog_temp(character_counter)),2^(bit_no-1));
        elseif(bit_no<8) % Test the unmodified program once
            continue
        end
        try
            eval(prog_temp);
            eval('ans(2,3)');
            disp(prog_temp)
            success(end+1)=1;   
        catch
            success(end+1)=0;
        end 
    end
end
assert(nnz(success)==1)
```

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##hVHdSsMwFL5unuLcjOZgN@j0QloGeuEbeDempO2pC7RJTdJt6nz2mmylmyB4kZB8f3yco0sndjTUsILFYjE8cJEUSO9cqU9e0bKQvJDuoM0JR0yM3lsuEIdK2o7HNV8mt5jFyM4vmMHToaPSUZWBMz2xi@5u0t391tWiscTYDJ7JOstYZ/SbEa2vFP/bx1NpkuLx@PWNcc6Y8q6gHTPQQ7YvS7LWE@tNzmptQPp3ChkoFoWvTwxAds@iKPheHbWdR8aM/BrmCj0zdqh0XzTEr0lMli@h4jxFDEZnPvwd0U40fD0JkziPN3ghYqHsaX7xhRlrc1LVTYqrMMwQWApXbv/gT0MMAv@PWLhZOEzWfFTiuItHBw0J60ArgrpXpZNawV5YCGV64XcCe@m2undAxmjjt0ZhQ6O9aSaXBUO2b4JDKhBQ6raTDc2dbAn8ZMdArzxDU5yqhh8 "Octave – Try It Online")

Comment: @ExpiredData Thanks for the suggestion. I went for a MATLAB `numel` instead, because my test suite does not seem to be working in Octave.

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##hVHdSsMwFL5unuLcjCTYDTq9kJaBXvgG3o0paXvqAmlSk3SbOp@9JlvpJgheJCTfHx/nmMqLHQ4NrGCxWAwPTKQlx3em9SercVlKVkp/MPaEc5562yMfauk6Rhu2TG95Tjk5v2AGT4cOK491DlFILrq7SXf3W9cI5ZCQGTyj846Qzpo3K9rQh/5bJlBZmvHj8eub04IQHVxRO2bwALm@qtC5QKw3BWmMBRneGeSgSRK/ITEC@T1Jkuh79dh2ARkzimuYaR6YsUNt@lIhuyZ5unyJFecZ59Ho7Ue4E9wJxdaTMKUF3fALQYV2p/nRCzPWZqjrm4yv4jBjYCV8tf2DPw0xCsI/IfEm8RDZsFHJx108elAonAejEZpeV14aDXvhIJbpRdgJ7KXfmt4DWmts2BrGDY12pSaXA4uuV9EhNQioTNtJhXMvW4Qw2TEwKM/QFKfr4Qc "Octave – Try It Online") maybe.. not got a matlab license but should work

Comment: @ExpiredData Thanks, one can actually do one byte better with `eye`!

Comment: is this strategy maybe better? `@(a,b)eq(nnz(diff(de2bi([a;b]))),eye)`

It's equivalent but i think this strategy can be golfed.

Comment: @ExpiredData Sadly, that fails on `[a:b]` and `[a+b]` also being valid programs.

Comment: 36? - `@(c,e)~(nnz(de2bi(bitxor(c,e)))-eye)`

Comment: @ExpiredData `@(c,e)~(nnz(de2bi(bitxor(c,e)))-eye)`
`@(c,e)~(nnz(de2bi(bitxor(c,e)))/eye)` There's a good reason why I'm avoiding numbers as well as operators.

Comment: Yes shame I can't test these as I go

Comment: @ExpiredData I know, I'm very annoyed at Octave too. But using the Python program in the OP comments is handy to see if you can introduce a new character without problems.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>77</s> 43 bytes

*Thanks to Jo King for -33 bytes.*

```perl6
{elems(i)eq(sum [+^](@_).polymod(+@_ xx*))}
```

This is equivalent to

```perl6
{1 eq(sum [+^](@_).polymod(2 xx*))}
```

`1` was rewritten as `elems([""])`. `2` was rewritten as `sum(elems([""]),elems([""]))`; `elems(["",""])` might seem to work but `elems([""-""])` is also valid and seems to hang the tester.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDRSsMwFH3uvuJSwmztWtrhFOw6OkZBULcHRZC5jeo6rWvsTDJYKf0W2V/4AfsRv6TepPNBktzk3Jx7Tm42CcvO6y1P4HYyvo4e7bsosscTO3oY3vgtWgDhEMBJXSZZQrmRmsmnwbcUptZ8ZoQL09nkWUHzpWGFC9jtTk2zqk8cwVKqqts/319YL9VAR/zUPuwDwn25635rlTPou@DhwNjrQvcMPPdvempistcDdwD2AEjcAfIMZUvjcQH6EQYDKNHHaKBZoXClnh6jtaveEa7xSLiTsyVvbOeYkoqpVFOJC4XfJdZkCcWScO0jCumUpDOw5gEYHlh9ZJl@wyJCsqjz8sa4TAlWKAHtX8vSXPiHveF2oGvqkth0MM4hYQzdVyynl0hq7iyLxOowGt6PrhpBbZms4m0moKwklAFXha0e/wJELuIMNjHn6ccrCtW/)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 20 bytes

```javascript
b=>d=>[i=d^b][i--&i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@TWqKQZvs/ydYuxdYuOtM2JS4pNjpTV1ctM/Z/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoaCgoGmhoKhpqaCvr5CSFFpSUYlF7oKQ6AKAzwqDE2NNDWMTPCZYQi0xRBqhltiTnEqdhV43QGU1TA0wmOGkakpwqU4bAG6VMEUWcV/AA)

[validator by Arnauld, modified (not use strict)](https://tio.run/##XVBda8IwFH33V1zKWBOqQWWDsapD3B72NvCxVIw1asQmLo3dhvS3dzf9cGUUSnLPxz05R57zLDHybAdKb0WZpzAFIz4v0gji56lPwzJBAKfeZjrbTmeRnG5XmziSg8G9jL2w19tpQ87WIGUYgjtMwEnYSai9PVSjIKBw7QE46kbamuoOE3iqDi0BQImvRb0wYow5ozjsAhHaxYgurZFqz3ZGp4sDNw4iXQpLmuncEgorGMFk4jbR2i2rAjcCdtRSEd9vsDPPMgTH9c2anyYa5r@oBBGR8xNBh4Z/U4zae54yc1HvaqGVFd@WrLtC7@6K2sKjYeVHRo9jSsYPdN13usQIbkUrvBa0WVJU/4Tb5EAElgXQ7Eq0yvQJ69Z7l6kPpE6DD4AX8KMzNxk2BcIYbWIfnnGG4axMRTujEICPXwCCWV03S@j/1w27QeSuWkNv1XRjeB/z5fLt1etDtyR7MPoLWuzPrOgVZfkL)